# Is there a way to find out which packages depend on a specific package (Julia)?

Tags: package, julia

As the title says, is there a way to find out which packages depend on a specific package in Julia?

Comment: also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642247/is-there-any-way-to-build-package-dependency-tree-in-julia-lang/36653358#36653358

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
julia> Pkg.dependents("JSON")
53-element Array{AbstractString,1}:
    ...
```

Note this only includes packages you have installed.